# Webpack error: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I have an angular 4 application using webpack. When i try to run in in my amazon server i get this error. Works fine in my local. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a valid question and I don't see why some people would downvote it.

Anyway I fixed the problem. My package.json had @angular/compiler-cli in the dependencies. Removing that solved the problem. I have @angular/compiler-cli in the devDependencies. Problem was faced only on ec2 machine.

Comment: Agree on it being a valid question. This finally saved me from days out of headache when my heroku app crashed due to having my angular compiler cli in the dependencies instead of devDependencies. Thank you for posting your solution!

Comment: I am still facing this problem although my @angular/compiler-cli is in devDependencies only.